# Getting started with hapi.js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am looking at making a simple hello world with the hapi.js tutorial.

I have installed hapi:

1. `npm init`
2. `npm install hapi --save`
3. I get a large set of folders with files

I tried doing `node index.js` and that gave me errors.  So I `cd` into `node_modules` and got another error when running `node`.  I `cd` again into `hapi` and again got an error when running `node index.js`.  I added all of the syntax from the tutorial.

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ 
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: 8000 
});

// Add the route
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path:'/hello', 
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('hello world');
    }
});

// Start the server
server.start();
```

Not sure where I should be running index.js

Comment: Error message please? Running the program inside node_modules will not gain you anything

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I made an app.js file and was able to get everything to work there.   However, it was in the node_modules.  when I npm install hapi I get multiple files with folders in them.  Do I ignore those and go about creating my usual folders for mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `node_modules` folder is used to store all the dependencies for your application (ie. `express`, `hapi`, etc). This would be similar to a `lib` (library) folder in other languages.

When you download dependencies using `npm install`, the `node_modules` folder will get placed at the root of your project. Your source files can be placed anywhere within the root or within subfolders you create. They shouldn't however, be placed in the `node_modules` folder since it is meant for external dependencies.

Contrary to the other answer, you're not restricted to executing the program in the root - you can execute it in any subfolder as well. When you run the program, if Node can't find the `node_modules` folder in the current directory, it will move up to a parent directory until it finds it. See Node's [modules documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore the `node_modules` directory. It is used by npm to install dependencies. You shouldn't make any changes in that directory. Your files should be in the project root:

```
your-project
  |__ node_modules
  |__ index.html
```

You need to execute `node index.js` in the project root, which in this case is `your-project`.

```
cd your-project
node index.js
```